# how make stored S3 bucket data searchable in marklogic 8 REST API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

In this case user directly stored unzip files (include xhtml, xml, html, doc, opf, images) in to S3 bucket. Now in our Marklogic search application, searches data from a single database which has four forest attachment and xml as data stored inside it. Now we want to extend our search application to include S3 bucket for search with our database. Also we want to keep S3 bucket document are read-only but forest document should be read write update delete. Please anyone suggest how make S3 data searchable without storing data from Marklogic to S3 and how connect database to S3 read only.

Answer (score 1):

For MarkLogic to be able to search the data, it has to be in a MarkLogic forest. You can set up a forest on S3 and load the S3 data into that forest. [Configuring MarkLogic for Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2/managing#id_98406) will provide the details. Notice the warning that you must turn off journaling for a forest on S3.